# Use wired LAN adapter by default

Tags: windows, networking, network-adapter

I am trying to find out if there's a way to set up network adapters so that if 2 are connected with network and internet access it will choose one over the other.

Scenario:
I have seen several computers running Windows 7 or Windows 8 where you are connected to a wireless network, working perfectly. Then when you plug in an Ethernet cable, it still shows the network icon in the taskbar as wireless.

I would like to have my computer set up so that if there's an Ethernet cable plugged in, it uses that, and not the wireless adapter.

1) Is this possible / How?
2) Why does it stay on wireless over wired when given the option for both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Yes,

```
 route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 x.x.x.x metric 1
```

not a huge Windows person so don't know how you could manually add that statement in when you plug in your Ethernet cable.  x.x.x.x is the IP address of the gateway of your wired connection.

2) Not sure why it chooses the wireless over the wired connection.  I don't have a Windows machine in front of me but I am guessing that the wireless default route has a lower metric than the wired default route, which is what the above would take care of.

I honestly thought they came in with equal metrics, in which case it would either try to load balance over both or choose the first one that comes up.

If you do a `route print` and do not see an all zeros route or only see one (when both are plugged in), ie the one for your wireless, then you are still connecting to the Internet but relying on proxy ARP when you do.  In which case fix your DHCP config to hand out a default gateway on both subnets; wireless and wired.

Hope that helps sorry if my explanation was a bit confusing... English is my third language :)